# Is there a way to run task scheduler on Selenium Python Script using PhantomJS?

Tags: python, batch-file, selenium, phantomjs

I have a web scraping code that uses Python Selenium and PhantomJS headless browser. I've created a batch file and used windows task scheduler to run the file everyday, it runs the script at the time allocated, however it does not seem to execute the script properly.

This is my batch file:

```
@echo off
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\mti_wllow\Desktop\scraper070715(WORKS).py %* pause
```

When I click on the batch file and run it myself, the scraping works. However it does not work using windows task scheduler. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: This might be related to sessions and privileges of the schedule task, usually scheduled task run with "Highest privileges", which causes it to run in the "system" session, so when you run it by schedule task you won't see the window. Try running it by schedule task and looking in the task manager(click on show processes from all users), can you see the process (python.exe/cmd.exe/chromedriver.exe) running in the system session?

Comment: Hi @equinox93 , it is definitely not running even when scheduled because I do not get new data scrapped into MySQL which is what the program is meant to do. Thank you though.